# Are Loaded / Unloaded events guaranteed to be raised in pairs?

Tags: wpf

I started out assuming that the `Loaded` and `Unloaded` events are guaranteed to be raised as a pair, however I'm (barring a bug in my own code) seeing behavior that suggests there's no such guarantee in the API. I don't see an explicit guarantee in the WPF documentation, and the behavior I seem to be seeing current is that that `Loaded` may be raised multiple times before any `Unloaded` gets raised.

Separate of this, I'm already aware of the behavior that during shutdown `Unloaded` may be skipped altogether.

If `Loaded` and `Unloaded` are not raised as a pair, what events can I use instead, akin to an *AddedToTree* / *RemovedFromTree*, that do get raised as a pair?

Background:
I have an in-memory data model (a directed tree) and a data bus that UI can subscribe to for data model mutation events. I'm looking for the correct timing vis-a-vis WPF callbacks for subscribing and unsubscribing to my data model mutation events. What I *don't* want is for orphaned or unloaded controls to be wasting cycles responding to mutations. What makes a callback "pair" guarantee desirable is that I would be able to assume during the "init"-like callback that I have "catching up" to do, to read completely/directly from the data model.

Comment: There is no such guarantee. Perhaps we could help more if you told us what you're *actually* trying to do?

Comment: @Sheridan Background information is added.

Comment: take a look at [MSDN Object Lifetime Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information about lifetime and events in WPF

Comment: @Jehof Hi Jehof. I have, thanks. My question still stands as-is. The documentation does not seem to offer an explanation for or affirmation of `Loaded` possibly being raised multiple times without paired `Unloaded`.